# I have to Re-install angular CLI every time i shutdown my PC

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm learning Angular 2 by following the getting started tutorial on Angular.io. I followed all instructions on the website installed the CLI correctly and started building my first app. my problem comes when i shutdown my PC and then try working on my project the next day it gives me this error:The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed even though I was working on it perfectly the day before so every time I end up Re-installing the CLI again!

versions:
@angular/cli: 1.2.7
node: 6.11.0
os: win32 x64

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here to help you diagnose and solve a problem: what system are you using; how did you install the CLI; what's the full error message?

Comment: I'm using windows 10, I installed it using the 'npm install -g @angular/cli' commad and the full error message is: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'. I'm sorry if my question is not clear, this is my first time using this website :)